# What does it mean that serializer validators are good because it makes it easy to switch between Model Serializer and explicit Serializer?

Tags: django, validation, serialization, django-rest-framework, backend

I've been reading the rest_framework document but I'm finding it hard to grasp the meaning of this sentence

"It is easy to switch between using shortcut ModelSerializer classes and using explicit Serializer classes. Any validation behavior being used for ModelSerializer is simple to replicate."

It's one of the three benefits of using serializer validators but...

1. Why would you switch between ModelSerilzer and Serializer class defined serializers?
2. What does it mean it's easy to replicate?
3. Why would I replicate a validator defined for a ModelSerializer?

Here is the link where it's written
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/

Thank you for checking out this question!

I tried looking up for the same question that talks about the replicable advantage of django serializer validators. But All I got was the fact that it's better to create model instance via serializers because serialziers have easy validating logic and that it's better to keep both serialzier validator and model validator.